# Merge ActiveRecord::Relation arrays with different columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to merge two ActiveRecord::Relation arrays to put together search results that span both questions and answers. I need the results to be in the form of a single ActiveRecord::Relation array so I can manipulate it further.

Here is the code:

```
question_results = Question.where("(body || title) LIKE ?", "%#{@search}%")
answer_results = Answer.where("body LIKE ?", "%#{@search}%").group("question_id")
questions = question_results.merge(answer_results)
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: question_id: SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions"  WHERE ((body || title) LIKE '%cosby%') AND (body LIKE '%cosby%') GROUP BY question_id
```

This is happening because the two tables have different columns, and specifically because questions do not have a question_id column.

Is it possible to merge these two results into one search result and still get back ActiveRecord::Relations? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins to retrieve fields from two tables when there is mapping available between them. Say Question(:id, :body, :title) has_many Answer(:id, :body, :title), then you can use joins to get all fields:

```
Question
.joins(:answers)
.select('questions.id as question_id, answers.id as answer_id')
.where("questions.body ilike ? or questions.title ilike ?",keyword, keyword)
.where("answers.body ilike ? or answers.title ilike ?",keyword, keyword)
.order('question_id')
```

For sample i have plucked few fields but you can include any fields from both the models. Also use alias(like question_id, answer_id) for tables with same field names.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Relation objects can be converted to arrays. This negates being able to use any ActiveRecord methods on them afterwards

```
questions = question_results + answer_results
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically trying to get the answer in the form of an ActiveRecord::Relation array.

Comment: HAve you tried adding has_many and belongs to relation in models

Comment: The models already have a has_many and belongs_to relationship. I don't see the relevance.